# Django HTML5 Boilerplate header and footer

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and set it up successfully and easily and also configured django-html5-boilerplate easily.  I am using Django 1.6.1 and django-html5-boilerplate 1.0.8.  However, I cannot figure out how to display header and footer across all child templates, and would greatly appreciate help.  This is the `default.html` that extends `dh5bp/base.html`:

```
{% extends 'dh5bp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load url from future %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/base.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
<header><h1>The site header</h1></header>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<footer><p>The site footer</p></footer>
```

And this is `index.html` that extends `default.html`:

```
{% extends "default.html" %}
{% block title %}The home page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}This main page is under construction.{% endblock %}
```

I have verified (on command line) that the runserver gets all static files from django-html5-boilerplate installation and also my own `css/base.css` that is in my application's static folder.  The `index.html` displays only the "content" message, no header or footer.  However, when I remove the first line `{% extends 'dh5bp/base.html' %}` from `default.html`, the header and footer defined in `default.html` are displayed in `index.html`.  Does django-html5-boilerplate require some other configuration for displaying header and footer?  Thanks a lot in advance.

Asif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Django template inheritance hierarchy, everything in a child template must be inside a block from the parent template. Your "default.html" is not the base template, so everything has to be in a block - but your header and footer are not, so they simply don't have anywhere to go.

They should be inside your `content` block, which should then define another block for the children to inherit:

```
{% block content %}
<header><h1>The site header</h1></header>
{% block child_content %}{% endblock %}
<footer><p>The site footer</p></footer>
{% endblock %}
```